# Error because of variable length optionals arguments (*args) in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, optional-arguments

I am trying to run below code in python 2 but getting Invalid syntax error.

```
    columns = ["col1"]
    funcs = val_to_list(funcs)
    exprs = []

    for col_name in columns:
        for func in funcs:
            exprs.append((func, (col_name, *args)))
```

I took this code from Python 3 project but i want to make it work in Python 2. I tried few combinations but not working. Please help!

Comment: _i want to make it work in Python 2._ Why?

Comment: Due to restrictions in my company environment..Lot of production code is still in Python 2 , so have to integrate with existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(col_name, *args)` creates a new tuple with `col_name` as the first element, followed by all the elements from `args`. This syntax is called [*iterable unpacking*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) and was [first added to Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations).

Just create the tuple by concatenating:

```
t =  (col_name,) + args  # assuming args is a tuple too
exprs.append((func, t))
```

If `args` is itself not yet a tuple, convert it:

```
t =  (col_name,) + tuple(args)  # works with any iterable.
exprs.append((func, t))
```